# Hash an integer by another integer

Tags: ruby, hash, hashcode

I'd like a way to hash an integer using another integer. It should produce a new hashed integer. It should accept an integer input and a key, the input is then hashed by the key and produced as an integer. The method would look like `hash_method(input, key)`. Collisions won't matter here, I am not using them for security or comparison. I'm pretty sure this is possible seeing how some security algorithms that use challenges do something similar. How would I go about this in ruby?

Comment: There are countless many ways to do this. Is there any restriction? Does it have to depend on the key? For example, is it wrong if it returned the original integer for any key? If so, what is wrong with it? What is the format of the key? Is it a string? or a number?

Comment: Yes it does have to depend on the key, essentially, I am pulling the integer from a perlin noise function by using `Perlin::Generator#[x, y].to_s.split(?.).last` and then I want to hash that with a key (most likely using `Symbol#hash`) and then return it to a float. I'm just not sure how to go about the actual hashing part. I want the method to essentially look like `get_perlin_value(x, y, key)`

Comment: What are your thoughts on collisions of the results? Do you want the result as integer itself?

Comment: I don't think collisions matter much here. I am more using it to create repeatably random results without having to create a new perlin generator for every new feature I add. I'll update the question to reflect this. The only thing i really care about is that the coverage of the hash is at least 1/2 of the integer space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash routines are many and varied, and usually picked to match details of expected input distribution, purpose of the hash value, and speed to generate them.

However, you can make use of existing hash routines in Ruby's standard library. The output of most cryptographic hash functions is a string of bytes that can easily be interpreted as an integer. For your purpose, you just need to decide on a suitable maximum value by restricting the length.

Cryptographic hashes also have the advantage in your case that they make high quality pseudo-random functions - given two inputs that differ by only a single bit, the results will not correlate.

The HMAC construct combines a hash function with two inputs - a message and a secret. Using your input number as the message, and key as the secret allows you to use the function as-is.

There is *nothing* special about using Integer inputs for most standard hashing function, which on the whole just munges bytes ignoring data types. Given that you don't seem to care about specific values that the hash outputs, *you can simply convert your numbers to `String` values and feed them into a standard hashing function*. This is perfectly OK, there is no reason not to do this, unless you need to differentiate between `1` and `"1"` using the *same* hashing function.

Like this:

```
require 'openssl'
input = 25
key = 106

full_hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest( 
  OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'), key.to_s, input.to_s )

# This is an unsigned 32-bit integer
result = full_hash[0..7].to_i(16)

#  => 2746028024
```

This result is suitable for checksums, or for algorithms that want pseudo-random re-distribution of values. It has a flaw, in that the speed will not be high in cases where you need to generate many values.

You could make this a lot simpler if you were happy with a lower quality of randomness - you could use a linear congruential generator for example. This would likely be faster than the above, but might exhibit unwanted patterns in the output.

Comment: Works well, although I was more interested in trying to find some basic hashing algorithms. This will work either way, thanks for the help.